# Cassandra Replication setup

Tags: database, cassandra, database-replication, ccm

I'am working with Cassandra 3.9 . I have some doubts like I'am currently having 2 physical machines and want to have data stored the best possible way :-

1) Either in a distributed order on both machines.
2) The other way to store complete data on 1 machine and replicate the entire copy onto the other machine. (first preference)

Now If I go with creating 2 DC having 3 nodes each i.e. in case of my setup 1 machine will have 3 local nodes and likewise second machine. So how will I make these 2 independent DC1 & DC2 communicate with each other ?

Also I tried using CCM for cluster setup , but It halts with an error **"CCM Warning Downloading 3.9.0 failed, due to not all arguments converted during string formatting."**

I was using this query when i get the error :- **ccm create --version 3.9.0 --nodes 3 --start test**

Comment: CCM Warning Downloading 3.9.0 failed -- Did you tired with other version, try some older version like 3.0 or some RC in Version  3.

Answer (score 0):

How cassandra distributes data check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587806/cassandra-sharding-and-replication/41590463#41590463) answer.

```
2) The other way to store complete data on 1 machine and replicate the entire copy onto the other machine. (first preference)
```

Your configuration in cassandra.yaml file decides where to put the data. Data replication depends on your keyspace definition -

```
CREATE KEYSPACE ums_db WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2', 'DC2': '2'} ;
```

For this schema definition, cassandra will copy each row in two different nodes. Cassandra will choose node in clockwise direction as explained in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587806/cassandra-sharding-and-replication/41590463#41590463) answer.

Now to make it working with two data centre, in your case two different machines, you need to specify proper snitch. Reefer [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchPFSnitch_t.html) page, this explains a property file snitch and cassandra-topology.properties, it defines Data centre configuration. The two DC will behave as one cassandra server. Each node can take role of co-ordinator, that server decides.